# Why is the magnetic field around a long current carrying wire tangential to the circles drawn about the axis?

Tags: magnetic-fields

[image]

While calculating the magnetic field around a infinite current carrying wire a circular ampèrean loop is consideured.Then it is said that the field is tangential to the loop.But how can it be said ? Even if the field is radial or say at 30° to the tangent to the field at all points even that would be symmetric.

Comment: $\oint \mathbf H \cdot d\ell = I$

Answer (score 0):

To find the direction of the magnetic field, the usual approach is to consider symmetries. This is because Maxwell's equations are invariant by isometries and the static solutions are unique. You need to be careful though; the magnetic field is a pseudo vector, so you get an extra sign when dealing with indirect isometries.

In your case, the fastest way is to consider reflections about planes passing through the $z$ axis. They leave the current invariant, so the magnetic field is perpendicular to it. Therefore, the magnetic field is orthoradial. In general, planar symmetry are always better to consider in magnetostatic since they directly give you the direction of the field.

Hope this helps.